# Can someone explain how add information to custom functions?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, dll, intellisense

I'm making a class library in Visual Basic .NET and I need some help on something.

Here's my class:

```vb
Imports System.Net

Public Class RequestAccess
    Public URL As String
    Public Function getRequest() As String
        Dim Client As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL)
        Client.Method = "GET"
        Dim Response As WebResponse = Client.GetResponse()
        Dim ResponseStream As IO.Stream = Response.GetResponseStream()
        Dim StreamReader As New IO.StreamReader(ResponseStream)
        Dim Data As String = StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
        StreamReader.Close()
        Return Data
    End Function
End Class
```

Everything is good.

There is just one thing I need: for information to show up via IntelliSense when referencing classes and functions.

Here's a picture of my function getting called:

[image: Function]

But I want it to look like this, with information about the function displayed below the function name:

[image: Other function]

Can someone please help?

If you don't get what I'm saying, look at the bottom of the function or subroutine; there's some white text explaining what the function does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [Xml documentation comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-xml-documentation-comments?view=vs-2019) to your function

```vb
''' <summary>
''' Summary goes here
''' </summary>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Function getRequest() As String

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: @GDMalachite: In the future, if you discover the answer to your own question, you can also answer the question yourself in order to share your findings with the community.